# Error Creating a Conditional Find Loop In Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, conditional-statements

I want to make a code to click a link while it's present on a page and the following the pages using a if or while loop, but when I run the code for selenium even with an if loop it searches for the previous item. Here is an example.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import randint
from timeit import default_timer

start = default_timer()

duration = (default_timer() - start)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "//MyPath to geckodriver")

driver.get("Examplewebsite.com")

rest=10


def check():
    datafile = driver.page_source
    found = False
    for line in datafile:
        if "Continue" in line:
            found = True
            break
    if (found = True):
        time.sleep(rest)
        elm4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='continue']")
        elm4.click()        
    else:
        elm5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='>']")
        elm5.click()


print (default_timer() - start)
while (default_timer() - start) < 1000:
    check()
```

With this code, when the program reaches a page with the ">" symbol instead of "Continue" it searches for "Continue" until the program fails instead of searching for ">"

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: if (found = True): should probably use == instead of = otehrwise it is always true.